# Private double variable, never gets updated

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

My result never changes and always goes to 0.

I am doing a dot product of two vectors. I can not use STL algorithms such as `std::inner_product`. So I need to write an iterator. The `operator=` should do the accumulation

```
template <uint32_t DIM>
double Vector<DIM>::dot(const Vector& rhs) const
{
    return  std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),accumulator(),multiply()).getresult();
}

class accumulator
{
    public:
        accumulator& operator++(){
            return *this;
        }

        accumulator operator++(int){
            return *this;
        }

        accumulator operator*(){
            return *this;
        };

        void operator=(double a){
            result=result+a;
        }

        double& getresult(){
            return result;
        }

    private:
        double result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returning by value in your dereference operator, creating a copy, which means that the value that has the multiply assigned to is a different instance for each assignment and is not the iterator instance.